# what does pip install actually do?

Tags: python, pip, package, pypi, pypiserver

Super newb question here..

What does pip install actually do?

Assuming the pypi package is a tarball...

Does it just download the tar.gz, unpack it and run setup.py?

Does it add the downloaded package to the site_packages folder?

I want to create a pip installable pkg using pypiserver so my colleagues can download my pkg in a painless way, but am a little unsure exactly what to include beyond the actual .py scripts.

Any guidance would be appreciated

Comment: Does this help: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/ ?

Comment: https://dev.to/alexbecker/how-pip-install-works-323j

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The tar.gz file is a source archive whereas the .whl file is a built
>   distribution. Newer pip versions preferentially install built
>   distributions, but will fall back to source archives if needed. You
>   should always upload a source archive and provide built archives for
>   the platforms your project is compatible with. In this case, our
>   example package is compatible with Python on any platform so only one
>   built distribution is needed.

See: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

You would typically not manually create the source archive and wheel, but use `setuptools` and `wheel` to do so for you.

Nowadays, many packages are wheels. While installing these wheels using pip, pip will:

> [...] unpack the archive in your current site packages directory and install any console scripts contained in the wheel.

See: https://wheel.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide.html#installing-wheels